# Log into a website using command line through a Progress 4GL UI

Tags: command-line, progress-4gl

I am using the command "start " to open a website when a user clicks a button. The button is part of a UI written in Progress 4GL (ADM). Using the "start" command I am able to open the website. But, is there some way to pass on Login credentials as well so as to log into the website?

Here's the code snippet I am using on click of a button -

```
OS-COMMAND SILENT start "<website>".
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters using a "?" in the URL. For example, to pass a search value into Google, you can use this URL:

```
OS-COMMAND SILENT START "http://www.google.com?q=searchvalue".
```

Your browser will display Google's page with "searchvalue" already in the Search field.

Look at the source of your webpage and find the username and password field names. Use those in the URL, separated by a "&". That should fill in the values when your `START` command opens the web page.